# Can't fix broken packages | E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, dpkg

I'm having issues trying any install or updates in my system, I tried the following commands:

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install
sudo apt remove --purge linux-image-generic-hwe-22.04
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

I also tried with these ones:

```
sudo chmod -R 755 /boot
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-5.19.0-46-generic_5.19.0-46.47~22.04.1_amd64.deb
```

**Complete output**

```
$ sudo apt upgrade
Leyendo lista de paquetes... Hecho
Creando árbol de dependencias... Hecho
Leyendo la información de estado... Hecho
Tal vez quiera ejecutar «apt --fix-broken install» para corregirlo.
Los siguientes paquetes tienen dependencias incumplidas:
 linux-image-generic-hwe-22.04 : Depende: linux-image-5.19.0-46-generic pero no está instalado
E: Dependencias incumplidas. Intente «apt --fix-broken install» sin paquetes (o especifique una solución).
```

```
$ sudo apt --fix-broken install
Leyendo lista de paquetes... Hecho
Creando árbol de dependencias... Hecho
Leyendo la información de estado... Hecho
Corrigiendo dependencias... Listo
Los paquetes indicados a continuación se instalaron de forma automática y ya no son necesarios.
  aspnetcore-targeting-pack-6.0 dotnet-apphost-pack-6.0
  dotnet-targeting-pack-6.0 liblttng-ust-common1 liblttng-ust-ctl5
  liblttng-ust1 linux-headers-5.19.0-45-generic
  linux-hwe-5.19-headers-5.19.0-45 linux-modules-5.19.0-45-generic
  linux-modules-extra-5.19.0-45-generic netstandard-targeting-pack-2.1
Utilice «sudo apt autoremove» para eliminarlos.
Se instalarán los siguientes paquetes adicionales:
  linux-image-5.19.0-46-generic
Paquetes sugeridos:
  fdutils linux-doc | linux-hwe-5.19-source-5.19.0 linux-hwe-5.19-tools
Se instalarán los siguientes paquetes NUEVOS:
  linux-image-5.19.0-46-generic
0 actualizados, 1 nuevos se instalarán, 0 para eliminar y 48 no actualizados.
2 no instalados del todo o eliminados.
Se necesita descargar 0 B/12,0 MB de archivos.
Se utilizarán 12,3 MB de espacio de disco adicional después de esta operación.
¿Desea continuar? [S/n] S
(Leyendo la base de datos ... 285477 ficheros o directorios instalados actualmen
te.)
Preparando para desempaquetar .../linux-image-5.19.0-46-generic_5.19.0-46.47~22.
04.1_amd64.deb ...
Desempaquetando linux-image-5.19.0-46-generic (5.19.0-46.47~22.04.1) ...
dpkg: error al procesar el archivo /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-5.19.0-46
-generic_5.19.0-46.47~22.04.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 no se puede abrir `/boot/vmlinuz-5.19.0-46-generic.dpkg-new': Operación no perm
itida
Se encontraron errores al procesar:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-5.19.0-46-generic_5.19.0-46.47~22.04.1_amd6
4.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: With the error: `The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  linux-image-generic-hwe-22.04 : Depends: linux-image-5.19.0-46-generic but not installed`, please install the missing package

Comment: The error appears to be "no se puede abrir `/boot/vmlinuz-5.19.0-46-generic.dpkg-new': Operación no permitida". I suggest investigating _why_ that file cannot be opened.